OpenShift roundrobin load balancer do not distribute traffic between pods
I've noticed very strange behavior of OpenShift load balancing. I make a call via internal route (not GTM) from one microservice to another. I additionally put roundrobin load balancing and disabled sticky session (this changes applied 100%)
haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance: roundrobin
haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies: 'true'

I performing requests via curl with connection reuse disabled
curl.exe $url -X GET -H "Connection: close" --no-keepalive

And with 2 pods for 20 requests I see very strangle behavior
With pause between requests:

100ms - 13/7
200ms - 16/4
1sec - 19/1
30sec - 20/0

The problem is that my service performing heavy computations, and pause in 20 seconds - it is production scenario. But in such case all requests came to a single pod, kill it, then to the second and kill it and so on.
I understand that round robin performed not only for a single endpoint which I am testing, but for all endpoints of a service. But any distribution between endpoints can't lead to situation 20/0 all the time. The problem is in something else and I do not understand where.
Can you please explain me why does it happened?
How can I achieve distribution at least close to 10/10 between 2 pods in a route?

Do you have a load balancer in front of the router pods? How many router pods have you deployed? What is the strategy of the load balancer?
If the load balancer sends requests using the round-robin method, do you also need to set the router pods to use round-robin?

haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance: roundrobin  and haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies: 'true'
applied to the OCP route. OCP Service using round robin by default out of the box. And I tried direct calls to the service - round robin works. I do not know how many pods of the router I have, because I do not have access to them
